# IPv6 LAN to IPv4 with PFsense

Tags: ipv6, pfsense

Is it possible to setup PFsense to do IPv6 to IPv4?

I am setting up an IPv6 LAN for "testing" and also to mess around with and I can't get an IPv6 address from my ISP so I need a way to change IPv6 to IPv4.

**Update**

Ok I upgraded to the PFsense 2.0 RC1 which has IPv6 support.

Under the "Advanced Settings" there are options for IPv4 NAT encapsulation of IPv6 packets.

There is a checkbox to enable the option and also a entry box that says "IP Address"

What do I enter there?

[image]

Comment: Do not put two different questions in the same post.

Comment: I did not think it was really 2 different questions, everything I am asking still falls under the main question, "How do I setup IPv6 to IPv4 with PFsense. If I am in the wrong I will happily repost in a separate question.

Comment: Migrating to Server Fault per @Solignis's request. Hopefully you'll be able to get some more detailed responses there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6to4 needs to know your extern IPv4 address that it should use. This will determine your IPv6 prefix by embedding the IPv4 address in your IPv6 prefix (basically your IPv6 subnet has the information necessary for other IPv6 hosts to find their way back to your IPv4 address via another 6to4 router.

Your ISP must support 6to4, or you must use a public 6to4 router.

<sub>PFsense is based on FreeBSD, I don't know PFsense's interface all that well, but I have an [Intro to 6to4](http://stoneyforest.net/~chris/blog/freebsd/ipv6/6to4intro.html) for the FreeBSD CLI on [my blog](http://stoneyforest.net/~chris/blog).</sub>

Comment: My ISP is Time Warner Business Class, they are the ones that told me to look for a router that can do 6to4 so I am assuming they support it.

Answer (score 0):

PFsense doesn't support IPv6, and won't until the next version (2.0).

Comment: Oh! I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

> What do I enter there?

You enter the IP address of the 6-to-4 tunnel broker.

Comment: So.... I would need to get a tunnel broker? Like He.net 6to4 service?

Answer (score -1):

You enter the IP address of the 6-to-4 tunnel broker.

This is correct, such as hurricane Electric. This is a PAID service.